# Microsoft SQL Server "There is already an object named 'geometry_columns' in the database" error

Tags: qgis, ogr2ogr, sql-server

I have trouble adding new layers to the existing MS SQL Server database. Whenever I try to add any type of spatial layer I encounter an error, as follows:

> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]There is already an object named 'geometry_columns' in the database. QODBC3: Could not complete command

I have tried manually deleting the geometry_columns table, but it also generates other error, so I am not able to do it. I have tried to establishing connection both with and without option "check only geometry_columns table". Also I've managed to add layers using OSGeo4W Shell command with ogr2ogr so it seems that only problem is within GUI of QGIS.
Is there a good way to baypass this error or some kind of workaround?

As it is shown on the screenshot below I have geometry_columns table inside DB user schema:

[image: Database schema]

Side note: The database itself was created with ArcCatalog, but now I need it to work also with QGIS

Comment: You shouldn't be creating or dropping this *table*, just insering/deleting *rows*.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that, but whenever I try to import shapefile from project via drag&drop to the database I encounter this error, I am unable to display or edit geometry_columns table. When I try to display this table I have following error:
> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'XXXXX\\15421214'. [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AND'. QODBC3: Could not complete command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that for some reason MS SQL DB automatically tries to create the geometry_columns and spatial_ref_sys tables (with the wrong create table statement). Actually deleting those tables in the users schema and creating them manually in "dbo" schema was a way to go.

Now QGIS works fine with the DB I can drag&drop layers without any errors and automatically adds layer info into those tables.