# Microsoft SQL Server "There is already an object named 'geometry_columns' in the database"

Tags: sql-server-spatial

Same question [Maciej_Szypulski asked](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/438838/2856), every time I try adding new layers to a new MS SQL server database i get the following error message. `[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]There is already an object named 'geometry_columns' in the database. QODBC3: Could not complete command.`

I noticed that there was an [answer as follows](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/439117/2856).

> I found out that for some reason MS SQL DB automatically tries to
> create the geometry_columns and spatial_ref_sys tables (with the wrong
> create table statement). Actually deleting those tables in the users
> schema and creating them manually in "dbo" schema was a way to go.
>
> Now QGIS works fine with the DB I can drag&drop layers without any
> errors and automatically adds layer info into those tables.

How did he create those tables in "dbo" manualy?